# Sikuli: How to get program to capture part of the screen and store as image

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

So I want to capture one image, image s, which is always in the same region. It then disappears and may or may not re-appear in a different region.

I would like the program to capture the first time it appears and if it re-appears in the other region, then click a set of buttons otherwise move to a different function.

The other thing is image s changes each time the function is called but it remains in the same location.

Below is my code:

```
def playLoop():

s = capture(firstRegion)
warnBox = exists("1443867801301.png")
if not warnBox:
    if exists("1443867813008.png"):
        click(x)
        playLoop()
    else:
        if secondRegion.exists(Pattern(s).similar(0.8)):
            wait(3)
            click(x)
            playLoop()
        else:
            loopLoop()
else:
    doubleClick(y)
    if secondRegion.exists(Pattern(s).similar(0.8)):
            wait(3)
            click(x)
            playLoop()
    else:            
        loopLoop()
```

I get no errors, however it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that you program is already finished before the given image has a chance to appear in another reagion. 
Have a look at `while not exists`.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you should change this:
   s = Screen.capture(firstRegion)
   for this: 
   s = capture(firstRegion)
2. You can get the coordinates with find(image):
   f = find(s)
   x = getX()
   y = getY()
3. Finally, if you want to get the numer of times, you can pass a variable to the function:

   ```
   def playLoop(times,x,y):

       s = capture(firstRegion)
       t = find(s)
       if times==0:
           warnBox = exists("1443867801301.png")
           if not warnBox:
               if exists("1443867813008.png"):
                   click(x)
                   times+=1
                   playLoop(times,t.getX(),t.getY())
       if times != 0:
           warnBox = exists("1443867801301.png")
           if not warnBox:
               if t.getX() != x or t.getY() != y: #different location
                   doSomething()
               else:
                   otherFunction() #same location
               times+=1
   ```

   PD: Sry if my english isn't  good :)

Comment: I have followed your first suggestion however, I am not really interested in getting the co-ordinates. All I would like is for the function to capture the first region and then when required see if the image captured exists in the second region. I have updated my code and question. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

To see if region1 exists in region2 you could use `if region2.exists(region1) then`.